# ANTLR handles strings as no viable alternative at input

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

So far I'm a total beginner with ANTLR but I can't even get a very basic Hello World program running properly. To start off, here is the relevant code(I think):

*Test.g4*

```
grammar Test;

kod
: påstående ';' kod
| EOF
;

påstående
:skriv
;

skriv
: 'skriv' STR
;


STR:('a'..'z')+ ;
WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip ;
```

test1.t(My test program)

```
skriv helloworld;
```

When I compile and execute the RunTest.java file, this is the output in the console:

```
line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'skriv'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Not sure what's wrong here. I have tried different inputs like numbers, quotations marks, equals signs etc but it all gives me the same error.

Comment: Does the problem persist when you define `'skriv'` as an explicit lexer rule above `STR`? Like `SKRIV_LITERAL: 'skriv' ; STR: ...`and then in rule `skriv` rever to that lexer rule instead of the indirect token definition `'skriv'`

Comment: It works for me (ANTLR 4.6). "test1.t(My test program)" : do you mean test data ? Try `grun Test kod -tokens test1.t` and `grun Test kod -gui test1.t` where `grun` is `alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'`.